# Android gallery images all grey

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, video, gallery, images

So I'm not sure or what causes this but in my gallery, a lot or most of my images and videos turn this grey color and only some can be opened, it's as if they have become corrupt.  Does anyone know why this happens or does anyone else ever run into this issue too?  I have g3 us990 running marshmallow Oct os

[image: my gallery with my grey images]

Comment: Clear .thumbdata files in DCIM folder. Also clear cache and data for media storage and external storage form app manager and reboot

Comment: it worked to show the thumbnails again but if I play a video or sometimes go into an album and back out, they go grey again and I have to close out of the app and reopen it to where it just repeats itself

Comment: Maybe is app the problem try with some other app

Comment: Yeah I have tried it with multiple apps and they all seem to do the same thing